# How to disable web storage in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've already tried to find a flag on the `about:about` page but found none.

I've also tried to start chrome with the `--disable-local-storage` switch.
But web storage is still available.

[image]

I check whether it is available or not by using this javascript code:

```
if (storageAvailable('sessionStorage')) {
  console.log("Web Storage available");
}
else {
  console.warn("Web Storage not available!");
}

function storageAvailable(type)
{
  try {

    var storage = window[type],
        x = '__storage_test__';
    storage.setItem(x, x);
    storage.removeItem(x);
    return true;
  }
  catch(e) {

    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Web storage is usually disabled when cookies are disabled.

Comment: But I need to only disable web storage, I need cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve it by starting chrome with these two switches:

`--disable-local-storage`
`--disable-session-storage`

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --disable-local-storage --disable-session-storage